# Implement Observer Pattern in C++

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, design-patterns, observer-pattern

The observer pattern can be really useful in event-driven systems. Here's how it might be implemented in two languages:

**Java**

Use an AOP library or byte-code engineering (BCEL, cglib, asm, etc) to create a sub-class on the fly. Any calls to the getter or setter of an observed property notifies any attached observers.

**Objective-C**

This is similar to Java - uses isa swizzling to create a sub-class on the fly. Any calls to an observed property notifies attached observers. Interestingly, in Objective-C we can swizzle back to the original class without the wrapped property methods, if all observers are removed. Whereas in Java a class is typically loaded once, so you're always notifying a (possibly empty) set of observers.

**How about C++?**

With limited reflection in C++, it would be difficult to use the above approaches. What is the "best" (by that I mean typical or defacto-standard) approach in C++? Is there any way to avoid the boiler-plate code like in the Java and Objective-C implementations that I referenced above? Perhaps using C++ meta-programming features?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you looking for an automatic way to implement this in C++?  As you mention, C++ doesn't have very powerful reflection, and so an automatic implementation is probably not possible.  Are you looking for a general purpose example?  Or for an automatic method?

Comment: Why did you tag this Obj-C and Java? Your question is regarding C++. You already have the answers for Java and Obj-C.

Comment: The observer pattern has no particular dependence on reflection or aspect-oriented programming.  They are implementation details.

Comment: @MJD I'm looking for the "best" (ie typical/standard) implementation in C++, preferably "automatic", if this is possible? The one that requires the least drawbacks, and makes the most of the language features at hand.

Comment: It can be implemented without any of that in any language, including C++.

Comment: @CaptJak I tagged Java and Objective-C because I'm interested in an answer that relates to the approaches taken in other languages. Go ahead and remove the tag if you think that its not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to implement the Observer pattern in C++ using just reflection.  If you don't use any external tools, you have to implement everything manually.  For instance, I'd implement it something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class Impl;

class ObserverBase {
public:
    virtual void propertyChanged(Impl *impl, int value) = 0;
};

class Impl {
public:
    void setProperty(int value) {
        if (m_property != value) {
            m_property = value;
            for(auto observer:m_observers) {
                observer->propertyChanged(this, value);
            }
        }
    }
    int getProperty() {
        return m_property;
    }

    void addObserver(ObserverBase *observer) {
        m_observers.insert(observer);
    }
private:
    int m_property;
    set<ObserverBase *> m_observers;
};

class Observer : public ObserverBase {
public:
    virtual void propertyChanged(Impl *impl, int value) {
        cout << "Saw new value of " << value << "!" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Impl impl;
    impl.addObserver(new Observer());
    impl.setProperty(5);
}
```

If you want ObserverBase and the for loop in Impl to be auto-generated, you could parse the C++ at compile time.  I don't know of anything that does that for you.

If you are using a third-party library, they may include tools to help.  For instance, if you are using Qt, you could use signal/slots to notify observers of changes.

Comment: Thanks @MJD. I will check out what Qt does. (I don't have a pressing requirement to do this right now, just interested in learning more C++). . . will accept an answer in next 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I write a lot of C++ code and needed to create an Observer for some game components I was working on.  I needed something to distribute "start of frame", "user input", etc., as events in the game to interested parties.

I also wanted it to be straight C++, not dependent on the platform or a specific technology (such as boost, Qt, etc.) because I often build and re-use components (and the ideas behind them) across different projects.

Here is the rough sketch of what I came up with as a solution:

1. The Observer is a singleton with keys (enumerated values, not strings) for Subjects to register interest in.  Because it is a singleton, it always exists.
2. Each subject is derived from a common base class.  The base class has an abstract virtual function Notify(...) which must be implemented in derived classes, and a destructor that removes it from the Observer (which it can always reach) when it is deleted.
3. Inside the Observer itself, if Detach(...) is called while a Notify(...) is in progress, any detached Subjects end up on a list.
4. When Notify(...) is called on the Observer, it creates a temporary copy of the Subject list.  As it iterates over it, it compare it to the recently detached.  If the target is not on it, Notify(...) is called on the target.  Otherwise, it is skipped.
5. Notify(...) in the Observer also keeps track of the depth to handle cascading calls (A notifies B, C, D, and the D.Notify(...) triggers a Notify(...) call to E, etc.)

This is what the interface ended up looking like:

```
/* 
 The Notifier is a singleton implementation of the Subject/Observer design
 pattern.  Any class/instance which wishes to participate as an observer
 of an event can derive from the Notified base class and register itself
 with the Notiifer for enumerated events.

 Notifier derived classes MUST implement the notify function, which has 
 a prototype of:

 void Notify(const NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T& event)

 This is a data object passed from the Notifier class.  The structure 
 passed has a void* in it.  There is no illusion of type safety here 
 and it is the responsibility of the user to ensure it is cast properly.
 In most cases, it will be "NULL".

 Classes derived from Notified do not need to deregister (though it may 
 be a good idea to do so) as the base class destrctor will attempt to
 remove itself from the Notifier system automatically.

 The event type is an enumeration and not a string as it is in many 
 "generic" notification systems.  In practical use, this is for a closed
 application where the messages will be known at compile time.  This allows
 us to increase the speed of the delivery by NOT having a 
 dictionary keyed lookup mechanism.  Some loss of generality is implied 
 by this.

 This class/system is NOT thread safe, but could be made so with some
 mutex wrappers.  It is safe to call Attach/Detach as a consequence 
 of calling Notify(...).  

 */


class Notified;

class Notifier : public SingletonDynamic<Notifier>
{
public:
   typedef enum
   {
      NE_MIN = 0,
      NE_DEBUG_BUTTON_PRESSED = NE_MIN,
      NE_DEBUG_LINE_DRAW_ADD_LINE_PIXELS,
      NE_DEBUG_TOGGLE_VISIBILITY,
      NE_DEBUG_MESSAGE,
      NE_RESET_DRAW_CYCLE,
      NE_VIEWPORT_CHANGED,
      NE_MAX,
   } NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;

private:
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T;

   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_MAP_T;
   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T>::iterator NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T;

   typedef vector<Notified*> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T;
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T;

   NOTIFIED_MAP_T _notifiedMap;
   NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T _notifiedVector;
   NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T _mapIter;

   // This vector keeps a temporary list of observers that have completely
   // detached since the current "Notify(...)" operation began.  This is
   // to handle the problem where a Notified instance has called Detach(...)
   // because of a Notify(...) call.  The removed instance could be a dead
   // pointer, so don't try to talk to it.
   vector<Notified*> _detached;
   int32 _notifyDepth;

   void RemoveEvent(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T& orgEventTypes, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   void RemoveNotified(NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T& orgNotified, Notified* observer);

public:

   virtual void Reset();
   virtual bool Init() { Reset(); return true; }
   virtual void Shutdown() { Reset(); }

   void Attach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for a specific event
   void Detach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for ALL events
   void Detach(Notified* observer);

   /* The design of this interface is very specific.  I could 
    * create a class to hold all the event data and then the
    * method would just have take that object.  But then I would
    * have to search for every place in the code that created an
    * object to be used and make sure it updated the passed in
    * object when a member is added to it.  This way, a break
    * occurs at compile time that must be addressed.
    */
   void Notify(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T, const void* eventData = NULL);

   /* Used for CPPUnit.  Could create a Mock...maybe...but this seems
    * like it will get the job done with minimal fuss.  For now.
    */
   // Return all events that this object is registered for.
   vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> GetEvents(Notified* observer);
   // Return all objects registered for this event.
   vector<Notified*> GetNotified(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T event);
};

/* This is the base class for anything that can receive notifications.
 */
class Notified
{
public:
   virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const void* eventData) = 0;
   virtual ~Notified();

};

typedef Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;
```

NOTE:  The Notified class has a single function, Notify(...) here.  Because the void* is not type safe, I created other versions where notify looks like:

```
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, int value); 
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const string& str);
```

Corresponding Notify(...) methods were added to the Notifier itself.  All these used a single function to get the "target list" then called the appropriate function on the targets.  This works well and keeps the receiver from having to do ugly casts.

This seems to work well.  The solution is posted on the web [here](http://www.nliapps.com/tools-you-build-part-i-observer/) along with the source code.  This is a relatively new design, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excellent work! Nice code, nice docs, great blog :) Look forward to trying this out.